# How to generate an Adobe Fillable PDF or PDF Form programatically in a Dot NET web application?

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe, using, fillable

I want to programatically generate an Adobe Fillable PDF using C# language of my web application, which is developed in Dot NET Core. When I share the generated PDF, it can capture the data of End users along with their signature. And the End users can use only an 'Adobe Acrobat Reader' (free software app) for filling the PDF form.

Is there an possibility for this Use case? Can I get the details of necessary API or Library? I need help or proper guidance in this regard?

**What I have tried**:
I have already used 'Adobe.PDFServicesSDK', a NuGet package of Adobe and executed a service / project code with the name 'MergeDocumentToPDF'(found in the sample service zip of sample projects, which is provided at the time of signing up a free Adobe Developer account). This is one among the 15 differenet services available in the zip file (package).

**Link to Sample Projects @ GitHub:**
https://github.com/adobe/PDFServices.NET.SDK.Samples

**Link to MergeDocumentToPDF service or project:**
https://github.com/adobe/PDFServices.NET.SDK.Samples/tree/master/MergeDocumentToPDF

According to the description of this sample project 'MergeDocumentToPDF', it merges the Word based document template with the input JSON data to generate a dynamic output document in the PDF format.

It is executed perfectly, and I got the PDF generated successfully. But when I try to edit the PDF after opening the same in an 'Adobe Acrobat Reader' (free software application), it is not permitting with that free app. And also, it is prompting to create an 'Adobe Professional' or 'Adobe Standard application' otherwise providing an option to choose a '7 (seven) day trial account for Pro app'. Unfortunately, none of these can be done by the End users of my web application. They can use only an 'Adobe Acrobat Reader'.

Actually, the Adobe Acrobat Reader (free app) is supporting to fill the Adobe Fillable PDF forms and allowing to submit them. I have experienced this and also confirmed with the support team of Adobe. Perhaps, I have decided to programatically generate a Fillable Adboe PDF rather than which I did using a service of MergeDocumentToPDF. But I didn't find any appropriate service or sample project zip/package for generating a Fillable PDF.

Perhaps, *I am assuming that I need to use another SDK or REST API or Library (package) of Adobe, for generating the Fillable PDF / PDF Form, that can be easily filled by any End user, using 'Adobe Acrobat Reader' comfortably*.

**Thank you!**

Comment: Please be aware that software recommendations are strictly speaking off topic on stack overflow. Nonetheless, what you need to look for are libraries that create PDFs with regular AcroForm forms, no proprietary XFA forms and nothing with overly funky JavaScript actions. There are numerous ones out there that do so. Maybe even Adobe libraries can do so but they may have a tendency to add Adobe Acrobat-only (and in particular Acrobat Pro-only) stuff.